# Is it possible for the reduction modulo $p$ of an non-commutative semisimple algebra to be commutative?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, linear-algebra, matrices, modular-representation-theory

Suppose that $I, X_1, \ldots, X_{d-1}$ are $n \times n$ matrices with integer entries whose $\mathbb{Z}$-span is a subalgebra of $\mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{Z})$. Suppose that, thought of as a subalgebra of $\mathrm{Mat}_n(\mathbb{C})$, this algebra is semisimple and non-commutative. Thus, by Wedderburn's Theorem, it is isomorphic to a direct product of complete matrix algebras $\mathrm{Mat}_r(\mathbb{C})$, with $r \ge 2$ for at least one factor.

> It is possible that there exists a prime $p$ and a field $K$ of characteristic $p$ such that, regarding $I, X_1, \ldots, X_{d-1}$ as elements of $\mathrm{Mat}_n(K)$ by reduction modulo $p$, the subalgebra of $\mathrm{Mat}_n(K)$ spanned by $I, X_1, \ldots, X_{d-1}$ is commutative, and still of dimension $d$?

As a follow-up, in my specific setup, the matrices are the orbital matrices for the action of a finite group $G$ on a set $\Omega$: the orbital matrix with $1$ in position $(\alpha,\beta)$ has $1$s exactly in the positions $(\alpha g, \beta g)$, for $g \in G$. It is known that these matrices span the centralizer algebra of the permutation module (over $\mathbb{Z}$ or any field). Moreover, the algebra is commutative in characteristic zero if and only if the associated permutation character $\pi(g) = |\mathrm{Fix}_\Omega(g)|$ is multiplicity-free.

> Is it possible that in this situation the centralizer algebra is non commutative in characteristic zero, but commutative after reduction modulo a prime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Example 5.10 of

*Towers, Matthew*, [**Endomorphism algebras of transitive permutation modules for $p$-groups.**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00013-009-3083-8), Arch. Math. 92, No. 3, 215-227 (2009)

(whose author you might know) gives a positive answer to the second question. The group action involved is of
$$G=\langle x,y,x\mid x^4, y^4, z^4, [x,y]=z\in Z(G)\rangle$$
(which has order $64$) acting on the cosets of the Klein four subgroup generated by $x^2$ and $y^2$,

Comment: Thank you very much Jeremy. Indeed, Matt and I overlapped as Ph.D. students of Karin Erdmann. What a nice example! I now don't feel so stupid for not being able to prove it yesterday. Somewhat embarrassingly I see I am thanked in the acknowledgements, so I really should have remembered this paper.

Answer (score 6):

Yes. For instance, a quaternion algebra is commutative modulo 2.

Comment: The regular action of quaternions doesn't identify $\pm 1$ as scalar multiples of each other which is needed for this example

Comment: Benjamin Steinberg's comment points out that this example doesn't (as I wrongly claimed in a previous comment) answer the second question. E.g. in the regular action of quaternions we have distinct matrices with zero/one entries representing $1$ and $-1$ and so $ij = k$ and $ji = -k$ are also distinct matrices.

Comment: I must have misunderstood the question. There is a $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra spanned by $1,i,j,k$, for example a subalgebra of $\mathrm{Mat}_4(\mathbb{Z})$, which I believe answers the first question. Actually, I think I didn't even see the second part of the question.

Comment: @Theo Johnson-Freyd: your answer is perfect for the first question, which was probably all you could see when you answered.

Comment: @TheoJohnson-Freyd Benjamin's comment was replying to a previous comment that has now been deleted, not to your answer.